# Getting InvalidOperationException while using a TextAreaFor html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use the TextAreaFor helper to display some notes about a clinical study. The notes are in an entity related to the Study entity called StudyNotes. I'm trying to display the notes for the study, something like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.StudyNotes.Where(x=>x.StudyId==Model.StudyId),new {rows="6",    
      @class="CarleTextArea"})
```

But I get this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just using an HTML textarea:
    @ViewBag.StudyNotes

In the controller:
    var studyNote = (from n in _db.StudyNotes
     where n.StudyId == study.StudyId
     select n).First();

```
if (Request.Form["StudyNote1"]!=null) studyNote.StudyNote1 = Request.Form["StudyNote1"];
```

Since I went after the associated note using the study id everything links up.